# Querying lots of tables at once in bq command line tool

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there an upper limit to the number of tables I can query when using the bq command line tool?

I have time series data that has been "sharded" (using tables) by date. I'm running the following query over a 152 day period:

```
SELECT LEFT(FORMAT_UTC_USEC(UTC_USEC_TO_DAY(timestamp*1000000)),10) as day, loc, count(*) FROM 
[mydata.20120601],
[mydata.20120602],
[usage_production.20120603],
[mydatan.20120604],
[mydata.20120605],
[mydata.20120606],
:
:
[mydata.20121031]
WHERE REGEXP_MATCH(actiondata, "up=[0-9]")
GROUP by day,loc
ORDER by day;
```

This query returns the data I expect when executed from the BigQuery Web interface, but when I run from bq command tool, I only get the first 22 days worth.

I'm using the following command line:

```
bq query --format=csv 'query'
```

Using bq on Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

There is no hard limit to the amount of tables that you can reference in a BigQuery query, other than the fact that the query must [fit within 10kb](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/quota-policy#queries).

The bq client currently has a [default limit of displaying 100](http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-tools/source/browse/bq/bq.py#868) result records from a query. However, you can use the `--max_rows` flag to change this value:

```
bq query --format=csv --max_rows 5000 'SELECT title FROM publicdata:samples.wikipedia LIMIT 5000'
```

Comment: That was it - I hit the 100 row output limit. Thanks!